# Jboss background validation

Tags: java, sql-server, datasource, jboss5.x

Our application had been using ping based approach where in before each query is executed.validation query is fired to check whether the connection is live or not. DataSource config for the same is as below:

```
  <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>250</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>90000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <track-statements/>
    <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 2</check-valid-connection-sql>.
```

Now in this approach we could see that there were tons of times when 'select 1' sql was getting executed and was unnecassarily adding upto the total cost for the operation.

When I searched for the possible alternatives was to do the connection checking in the background.

Datasource config for the same is as below:

```
<min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>250</max-pool-size>
<blocking-timeout-millis>90000</blocking-timeout-millis>
<track-statements/>
<new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
<check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 2</check-valid-connection-sql>
<validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
<background-validation>true</background-validation>
<background-validation-millis>600000</background-validation-millis>
```

My question is is this recommended?Is there any negatives if we used above approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the default behaviour, but it's a perfectly good option when you have very frequent queries, like in your case. You are right, this will significantly improve the latency of your queries.

The only downside is if something wrong happens to the connection between the validation period `background-validation-millis`. In this case, your query will fail, so, review your error handling code. I think it's a pretty cheap price to pay for the performance increase you might get.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @Apinto for confirming what I thought should be a good thing to do for load intensive application.Well I recently released these changes for the testers to test it.They have come back saying that performance has degraded..we have some methods calls and logging stuff to measure the performance of these methods while load testing... but I dont think this change in anyway will degrade the system..why do you reckon ...? to me it seems that it is probably some issue withe the network or someother thing